# How can I move to another page (exporting variables) in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-framework-7

I'm developing a web app with Framework7. I'd like to move to another page when clicking a link, exporting a variable.

In **index.php** I have this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc(xyz) {
            localStorage.setItem("variable", xyz);
        } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    foreach( [...] ) {

        [...] // something not important

        print('
            <a onclick="myFunc('.$myVar.')" href="anotherPage.php">'.$myVar.'</a>
        ');

    }
?>
</body>
```

In  **anotherPage.php** I have this:

```
<p id="example"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("variable");
</script>
```

I don't know why it does not work... Can you help me?

**P.S.:**
I found this that may be useful: [Ajax pages | Framework7](https://framework7.io/docs/pages-ajax.html)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

F7 is a SPA framework, it loads the new page without JS.
You should add a pageInit callback in you **index.php**

```
<a href="anotherPage.php?variable=xyz"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myApp.onPageInit('another-page', function (page) {
       // here is the variable
       console.log(page.query.variable);
    });
</script>
```

**anotherPage.php** should be formatted like this

```
<div class="navbar">

</div>

<div class="page" data-page="another-page">
  ...
</div>
```

There is another way to pass the variable by 'query' object.
https://framework7.io/docs/router-api.html

```
mainView.router.load({
  url: "anotherPage.php",
  query: {
    variable: 'xyz',
    ... 
  }
});
```